# Can this question be reopened? I have an answer now

Tags: support

I posted this question, asking if there was an alternative Bash emulator for the Windows Ubuntu emulator. It was closed as asking for a recommendation. I was asking if this was possible and not for a product information.

I just discovered that any terminal emulator can run Windows Bash by typing `bash` into the prompt. I would like to add this as the answer to my own question.

This is the question I would like opened: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748625/is-there-a-way-to-use-an-alternative-terminal-emulator-for-windows-ubuntu-bash*

For those who cannot see deleted posts:

> When I am using the terminal on my mac I can use iterm2 or Cathode or
>   any number of terminal emulators. Now that Windows has the Ubuntu
>   Linux sub-system, is there a way to use the Ubuntu bash it provides
>   with terminal emulator other than the one built into windows? The
>   built in terminal isn't much better than cmd.exe.
>
> I want to use the new Ubuntu Linux sub-system with a better/different
>   terminal emulator than the one that comes built into Windows.

Comment: Well, it wasn't just *closed*, it was *deleted*, too.  You're going to have to convince me (like really convince me) that it's worth undeleting that question.  Just because it has an answer doesn't necessarily mean that it's suitable for the site, y'know.

Comment: You haven't done anything to make the question any less off topic.  The fact that you have an answer to *an off topic question* doesn't make the question any more appropriate for the site.

Comment: Asking if *what* was possible? You said you were asking for an alternative tool. You didn't describe a task you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: How would I make this more on topic then? This is a question that has come up. I would like to make this question/answer fit.

Comment: I apologize for calling it bash shell. I have the same nitpick for vin number.

Comment: @Makoto, my question is about how to access the Ubuntu linux sub-system from an alternative shell. When I originally asked the question I thought that this required a terminal emulator that was built for it. The answer to the question makes the question not a request for an alternative, but it instead turns it into a question of how to do something. That is why I think the question should be un-deleted. Otherwise I wouldn't bother.

Comment: @FrankRobertAnderson I don't really see any way for this to be on topic.  That it's a question that you came up with doesn't mean that it's automatically on topic on SO.

Comment: @Servy, please let me know what is making it off topic. It was off topic because it was asking for a recommendation. Now it is not doing that, so why is it still off topic?

Comment: @FrankRobertAnderson It's not even a programming question, and anyway, asking, "does a product that does X exist?" isn't meaningfully different from asking for a product recommendation, and has all of the same problems.

Comment: @Servy, are questions about bash considered off-topic? "does a product that does X exist?" isn't an accurate description of my question.  As I said before, the question changed when I found the answer. This isn't a request for a recommendation or even asking if something exists any more. I need to access bash from any win console. I consider this about programming because without needing it for programming I would not need to know how to use these development tools on Windows. I am not asking how to copy and paste, or run a script in MS Word. This is task that pertains to software development.

Comment: If you've edited the question, can you post what it looks like now here? Users under 10K can't view deleted posts so if you're just editing the deleted question I can't see that.

Comment: @BSMP, I am not sure how well this will come out in a comment. The new body is as follows: 
"When I am using the terminal on my mac I can use iterm2 or Cathode or any number of terminal emulators. Now that Windows has the Ubuntu Linux sub-system, is there a way to use the Ubuntu bash it provides with terminal emulator other than the one built into windows? The built in terminal isn't much better than cmd.exe.

I want to use the new Ubuntu Linux sub-system with a better/different terminal emulator than the one that comes built into Windows."

Comment: If that version showed up as a new question, I expect it would quickly be closed as Off Topic - specifically of the "you might be better off asking on Super User" variety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem with this question is that it's not about programming, making it off-topic for Stack Overflow (although possibly making it on-topic for other sites). From [/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Your question fits the third point, as terminal emulators are commonly used by programmers, but doesn't fit the fourth criteria of being "unique to software development". Office chairs are also commonly used by programmers, that doesn't make questions about them on-topic here :-)

The reason for this isn't because those are unreasonable or "bad" question in and off themselves. You can ask many intelligent and useful questions about office chairs! The reason is simply because people who have *expertise* in programming usually don't have expertise in office chairs. It's just a matter of connecting experts with interesting questions for them to answer.

---

The second problem is that it looks like a "software recommendation" question:

> I want to use the new Ubuntu Linux sub-system with a better/different terminal emulator than the one that comes built into Windows.

These are are off-topic on almost all sites, as they tend to attract opinionated and incomplete answers. It's again not an unreasonable question *as such*, but it's simply not what we do, or really have the tools to manage.

---

We *do* have https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. But even there this question would be off-topic *as it stands*, as [the rules](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that site require:

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features

Which you didn't really provide.

You could consider re-posting your question there if you can make it fit the rules (if you don't, it will meet a similar fate as it did on Stack Overflow). Please do check if the question has already been asked, [a quick check reveals that it might be](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows+command-line).

Comment: FINALLY! I see someone enforcing the 4 point, which is pivotal for the site scope.

Comment: @Braiam I think the "problem" with that fourth point is that it wasn't phrased like that until fairly recently (last year, I think), before that it was "a practical, answerable problem that encountered software development", or something to that effect. So 1) lots of people don't know about it, 2) the *de-facto* rules means that a lot of stuff is allowed anyway, because it was allowed in the past (it's difficult to forbid something that was allowed in the past).

Comment: "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" has been like that since May-June '14, so that's not the "problem". The problem is that people think the list is a logical disjunction instead of conjunction, which is fault of the way it's formatted with bullet points of the same rank.

Comment: Oh, it's longer than I remembered @Braiam. Still, June 2014 isn't that long, and it gives a large "but these questions were allowed so why isn't mine?"-effect. We still get that with terrible 2008/2009 questions ;-) But yes, I do agree that the formatting is sub-optimal.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation @Carpetsmoker. My problem was that I didn't understand what my question should be until after I found the answer. I did a general search and found nothing that looked at all relevant, even if it was relevant. I probably could format the question properly, but it would likely still get low quality recommendation answers. So I will not be reposting.